# How to access Session and Application variables in SignalR Hub

Tags: vb.net, signalr-hub

I need to read Session variables (of the client calling the hub method) and read/write Application variables in a Sub inside the Hub class.

This doesn't work:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("varname")
```

And this doesn't work either:

```
Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Session("varname")
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: [SignalR troubleshooting](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting): "SignalR does not support the ASP.NET session state, since enabling the session state would break duplex messaging."

Comment: Thank you. I found out Application variables work using the code I posted. As for the Session variables, I passed them to the hub from javascript. All good now.